# Can you configure TeamCity "Artifacts" to be checked back into source control?

Tags: build-process, build-automation, teamcity

I would like to have TeamCity Artifacts be checked back into source control.

I have used TFS Integrator before. So I am used to its approach where, through config, it can check in the output builds back into source control. Then when people do a get they will receive these artifacts.

Or is there a completely different way of achieving this with TeamCity?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The two ways I can think of are

- VCS Labeling

specify a path in your working directory to label and the location relative to the trunk to check it in. [jetbrains explains it here](http://www.jetbrains.net/confluence/display/TCD4/VCS+Labeling)

```
/project/trunk/dist=>/project/tags/%system.build.number%
```

- from the build script

manually checkin the artifacts from the build script and add an ignore to the place where your checking in to so it doesn't trigger the build again.

```
e.g. use -:user=devA:project/sources/** to prevent build triggering after a change of VCS user devA  made in subfolder project/sources/**
```

Comment: Scott, could you provide some more detail (or perhaps a link to an example) on the second method?